# How can I migrate a custom submenu with ir.actions.server from Odoo9 to Odoo12?

Tags: migration, odoo-12

I have a module with custom submenu for transfers in Odoo9.

In the xml, I have this code:

```xml
<record id='action_menu_location_transfer_server' model='ir.actions.server'>
  <field name="name">Custom Transfers</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="model_wizard_location_transfers_internal_transfer"/>
  <field name="state">code</field>
  <field name="code">action = self.custom_get_transfer_views(cr, uid, context=context)</field>
  <field eval="True" name="condition"/>
</record>


<menuitem id="menu_refund_returns"
         name="Custom Transfers"
         action="action_menu_location_transfer_server"
         parent="stock.menu_stock_warehouse_mgmt"
         sequence="1"
         groups="base.group_user"/>
```

But in Odoo12, if I try to use the code, it shows this error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 350, in safe_eval
    return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1269, in run
    result = request.env['ir.actions.server'].browse([action_id]).run()
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 553, in run
    res = func(action, eval_context=eval_context)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 444, in run_action_code_multi
    safe_eval(action.sudo().code.strip(), eval_context, mode="exec", nocopy=True)  # nocopy allows to return 'action'
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 373, in safe_eval
    pycompat.reraise(ValueError, ValueError('%s: "%s" while evaluating\n%r' % (ustr(type(e)), ustr(e), expr)), exc_info[2])
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/etc/odoo/server12/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 350, in safe_eval
    return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: <class 'NameError'>: "name 'self' is not defined" while evaluating
'action = self.custom_get_transfer_views(cr, uid, context=context)'
```

What is the problem with the code for Odoo 12?

I have tried with self, record, object and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```xml
<record id='action_menu_location_transfer_server' model='ir.actions.server'>
  <field name="name">Custom Transfers</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="model_wizard_location_transfers_internal_transfer"/>
  <field name="state">code</field>
  <field name="code">model.custom_get_transfer_views()</field>
  <field eval="True" name="condition"/>
</record>
```

the 'cr, uid,' no longer used in v12,

you can add the code of the 'custom_get_transfer_views' method to correct

Comment: Is this french? Lol, I never imagined that I would learn other languages in stackoverflow :)